# example that the existence of the limit of this sequence does not imply the existence of $f'(c)$

Tags: real-analysis

If $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $c \in \mathbb{R}$, show that
$f'(c) =\lim (n(f(c + 1/n) - f (c))$
However, show by example that the existence of the limit of this sequence does not imply the
existence of $f'(c)$

---

I want to know the only second part of the question.
I think $f(x)=[x]$ is the required example. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct yes!.
 
Another example is $f(x)=\begin{cases}1, \ x\geq0\\
0, \ x\lt0\end{cases}, \ \ \ $ at $c=0$.

Answer (score 0):

A possible counter-example (for $c=0$) is $$
  f(x) = \begin{cases}
    x &\text{if $x = \frac{1}{n}$ for some $n$} \\
    0 &\text{otherwise.}
  \end{cases}
$$

Then $$
  \lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) - f(0)\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(\frac{1}{n} - 0\right) = 1 \text{,}
$$
but $f$ is not differentiable at $0$ because if you pick a different sequence you e.g. get $$
  \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{\pi}\left(f\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right) - f(0)\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{\pi}\left(0 - 0\right) = 0 \text{.}
$$